# xubuntu 10.04 install for 64bit i686

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, 64-bit, xubuntu

Does someone know how do i install XUbuntu 10.04 64Bit on i686?
Looks like in the download area there is only 64Bit version for AMD and not for i686..

http://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/linux/ubuntu-cdimage/xubuntu/releases/lucid/release/

10x.

Comment: What's wrong with the i386 version?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, but i still did not get it, sorry. I have a 64 Bit processor and i want to use a 64 Bit OS. Which xubuntu should i download ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i686 is a 32-bit architecture. EM64T is the Intel 64-bit architecture that it will run on.

Comment: Though I think you mean AMD64, which is much more common even in Intel chips. EM64T was used with Itanium. Or do I remember wrong? :)

Comment: @Janne: Itanium is IA-64. EM64T is Intel's X86-64-compatible technology.

Answer (score 0):

- amd64 work with 64-bit processors
- i386 work with any processors

If you don't know type of processor, use i386.

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flag
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow constant_tsc rep_good nonstop_tsc extd_apicid pni monitor cx16 popcnt lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt nodeid_msr
```

lm is Long mode - 64 bit CPU

Comment: nitpicking... i386 doesn't work on __any__ processor.  Like PPC, Arm, Alpha, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend NOT using a 64bit version of Linux, mainly because of the utter lack of flash support.

You can still use more than 4GB of RAM if the kernel is compiled with Physical Address Extension.

Comment: That's being fixed. http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/flashplayer10.html

Comment: Oh thank god for that, I hope it sees the light of day.

Comment: This is a system administration site.  I suspect the vast majority of us don't care one bit about running flash on our servers.  On the slight chance we do need to run it, we would be able to easily get it using a x86 chroot.  IMHO it would be very silly to accept the overhead of PAE just to run flash on a server.

Comment: Well if you're on a server, why use xubuntu instead of ubuntu server?